# Block diagram in electrical circuit

Tags: circuitikz, block

I'm new to LaTeX and I don't know how to put a block diagram in an electrical circuit.

[image]

I'm all done with it except the block with G.

Here is my code :

```
    \begin{circuitikz}[scale=3]
\draw (0,1.5) 
to [ european resistor=$R$] (1.35,1.5)
to [fullgeneric=$L$] (2,1.5)
to [capacitor=$C$] (3,1.5)
to [short,i=$i(t)$](3,0)
to(0,0)
to(0,1.5)

;


\end{circuitikz}
```

So what's the hack with that block, I don't have any idea.

Comment: I still prefer elmech, assuming this is a generator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}          % <---
\newcommand\ds{\displaystyle} % <---

\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}[scale=3, european]
\draw (0,1) to [R=$R$] ++ (1,0)
            to [L=$L$] ++ (1,0)
            to [C=$C$] ++ (1,0)
            to [short,i=$i(t)$] ++ (0,-1)
            to [twoport,t=\Large $G$, 
                l={$\xrightarrow[\ds u_e(t)]{}$}]   (0,0) % <---
            -- (0,1);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

gives:

[image]

**addendum:**

If you like to have circuit's elements on opposite side, than you can write:

```
\draw (0,1) to [R,a=$R$] ++ (1,0)
            to [L,a=$L$] ++ (1,0)
            to [C,a=$C$] ++ (1,0)
            to [short,i=$i(t)$] ++ (0,-1)
            to [twoport,t=\Large $G$,
                l={$\xrightarrow[\ds u_e(t)]{}$}]   (0,0) % <---
            -- (0,1);
```

or

```
\draw (0,1) to [R,l_=$R$] ++ (1,0)
            to [L,l_=$L$] ++ (1,0)
            to [C,l_=$C$] ++ (1,0)
            to [short,i=$i(t)$] ++ (0,-1)
            to [twoport,t=\Large $G$,
                l={$\xrightarrow[\ds u_e(t)]{}$}]   (0,0) % <---
            -- (0,1);
```

in both cases the result is the same:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I solve now the problem with the G inside the block but I can't to draw a vector u_e(t),

```
 to [twoport,t=\Large $G$] (0,0)
```

Comment: Please edit your question, or post a comment. This is not what answers are used for :)